# Cannot find Aptana Preview button in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana, aptana3, eclipse-luna

I cannot find out aptana preview in my eclipse,
after installing aptana plugin to my eclipse.
Eclipse version is Luna. 
In every tutorial sites, show preview button between terminal and apatana start page. But I cannot find it. Can anybody tell me how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm in the Web perspective and a html file is opened but no preview button exists and I can't add it in the perspective settings. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's displayed only if the current opened file is a html or a webpage